# "Karate" & "Cucumber for Java" plugins are overlapped in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, karate, cucumber-java

I have installed both "Karate" and "Cucumber for Java" plugins in IntelliJ. I can not keep both plugins enabled at the same time. If I keep both enabled then, my feature files of a Cucumber Java project are shown as Karate feature files and can not be run as a Cucumber feature file. So every time I need to disable Karate to work on the Cucumber project and disable the Cucumber plugin to work with the Karate project. It requires a restart of IntelliJ when we enable/disable the plugin.

Do we have any alternative to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Switch registered `*.feature` file type between `Karate feature file` and `Cucumber scenario` under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types | Recognized File Types`

This way you won't need to restart the IDE because of disabling Karate plugin