# Starting Karate and Cucumber tests with IntelliJ Cucumber-Plugin – no longer works using Karate 1.4.1 (worked fine in 1.3.1)

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, karate

For our test setup we have backend tests using the karate framework and frontend tests using cucumber. Both test suites are in different projects (we usually open both inside the same IntelliJ instance as modules).

Up until now we used the provided Gherkin and Cucumber-for-Java Plugins and this worked quite well, meaning we could start the tests – both the selenium/frontend and karate/backend – directly in IntelliJ using play icon in the gutter.

N.B. Using the Karate-Plugin additionally broke our frontend tests (and without a karate license brought us no additional functionality).
(see ["Karate" & "Cucumber for Java" plugins are overlapped in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76460701/karate-cucumber-for-java-plugins-are-overlapped-in-intellij) -- using karate- and cucumber-plugin in parallel does not work but was not needed as well).

This worked fine up until karate version 1.3.1. After Installing v1.4.1 the icon in the does no longer work: The gutter icon shows the “Nothing here” message (I know, there are many threads for this problem. This seems to be something new with the most recent version).

Comments:

- I already tried to start both frontend and backend tests in separate IntelliJ instances.
- When downgrading to Karate 1.3.1 works everything fine again.
- There is no version available between karate v1.3.1 and v1.4.1
- As I mentioned, using the karate plugin would not work for us.

Questions:

- Has anybody else encountered this problem with version 1.4.1? Is there a solution or a workaround?
- Is this intentionally from the karate makers to push the licenced versions?

By the way: How did the Gherking/Cucumber-Plugin differentiate between the different frameworks so as to choose correctly if a test was a regular Cucumber-Test (that needed to refer to glue code) or a Karate test (running directly without additional glue code)?

Obviously cucumber and karate feature-files needed to be in different projects but appart from that it worked fine up until karate v1.3.1
(describes a problem, when both are in the same project, so I assume the cucumber plugin was aware of the dependencies in the project, see [Is it possible to have Cucumber steps and Karate steps recognised at the same time in different feature files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397532/is-it-possible-to-have-cucumber-steps-and-karate-steps-recognised-at-the-same-ti))

Comment: you may get some hints from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76294302/143475